# sqlite.swift, how to give field value via name?

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

as the [example](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/) :

```
for user in try db.prepare(users.select(id, email)) {
   print("id: (user[id]), email: (user[email])")
   // id: 1, email: alice@mac.com
}
  // SELECT "id", "email" FROM "users"
```

but I want know if possible use name but expression or index ?

I meaning :

let id = user["email"] then got the value of the field 'email'

seem it not support ?

Comment: I have modify the code support the way...

Answer (score 0):

No, SQLite.swift does not support accessing row columns by their name.

An alternative is [GRDB.swift](http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift), which lets you access columns values by column name if you want to:

```
// Using raw SQL:
let rows = Row.fetchCursor(db, "SELECT * FROM users")
while let row = rows.next() {
    let id: Int64 = row.value(named: "id")
    let email: String = row.value(named: "email")
}

// Using a "query interface request", and raw row access:
let request = User.all()
let rows = Row.fetchCursor(db, request)
while let row = rows.next() {
    let id: Int64 = row.value(named: "id")
    let email: String = row.value(named: "email")
}

// Using a natural "query interface request":
let users = User.fetchAll(db) // [User]
```

Comment: I am appreciate with your comment, I have modify the code support the way..

Comment: but not sure if is right choice to continue use the swift.sqlite   ^0^ 

maybe GRDB is more better, I just want it simply, the swift.sqlite is great, just a little confuse on access the value , which use Binding that is not easy to extends and seem not very flexible ...  I have to update the code to meet my idea, then it works , will release the code on git soon.